# Returning javascript code upon Ajax complete

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I was just wondering if this was proper.

Is it possible to execute javascript code that has been return from an Ajax call?

```
ser = $('#new_customer_ input').serialize();

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: "ajax/newCustomer.php",
data: ser,
success: function(data)
    {
        $('div#result').html(data);
    }
});
```

Suppose the php file returns something like this:

`<script>$('input#customer_name').val('something');</script>`

which would be executed upon response.

This works, although my question is: is this correct or should I be doing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
eval('js_code');
```

for that. But make sure about the code in the string is from a very reliable source, (may be from your on web service).

The way you are doing it is correct. And better not use eval

Comment: Thanks!! I discover things sometimes, but I'm not always sure it's good practice or what I'm doing is actually "ok" to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say what you're doing is not wrong, but the problem is that your JavaScript won't tell you the whole picture. Since you're generating js from PHP, and loading it through Ajax, it may become difficult to understand what is going on when you try to analyze and debug that code. For example, you see the value from `input#customer_name` change, but you can't find the code that changes that, because it's being generated by PHP and served dynamically.

I would recommend sending just data from PHP, and keeping any logic that uses that data on the js files. Considering the code you posted, you could just `echo 'something'` on the PHP, and then do this from js:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "ajax/newCustomer.php",
    data: ser,
    success: function(data)
    {
        $('input#customer_name').val(data);
    }
});
```

If you need to send more complex data, you can use PHP arrays encoded as JSON (`echo json_encode($myarray);`). Then on JavaScript `data` will be an array or object, and you can loop it, access named properties, and so on, as needed (jQuery will automatically parse the JSON for you).

For example, consider the following PHP:

```
$array = array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'bar' => true,
    'baz' => 5
);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Given that, the `data` argument on your ajax callback will be a js object that looks like this:

```
{
'foo' : 'bar',
'bar' : true,
'baz' : 5
}
```

You can access those properties using `data.foo`, `data.bar` and `data.baz`.